How can I find Multiple Flask-SQLAlchemy Instances?
I'm currently running:
python3 -m flask --app  'flask_app.app:create_app("src.flask_app.config.DevelopmentConfig")' db migrate
and getting an error:
RuntimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app. Import and use that instance instead.
Any idea how I'm getting multiple instances or how can I find the instances?  I only declared SQLAlchmey once (I double-checked by scanning my code) with the below declaration:
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
  pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
migrate = Migrate()

I then import the db object into my app factory (where I run db.init_app(app) and migrate.init_app(app, db).  I also import db into the files where I declare my models.  The models are then used in blueprints in their respective directories.
Below is the structure of my project and how/where I import the db object
├── migrations
├── .envrc
├── requirements.txt
├── alembic.ini
├── __init__.py
├── flask_app
│   ├── model.py (db and migrate objects declared here)
│   ├── app.py (from .model import db, migrate)
│   ├── landing
│   │   ├── landing_templates
│   │   ├── models.py (from flask_app.model import db)
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── user
│   │   ├── user_templates
│   │   ├── models.py (from flask_app.model import db)
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── templates
├── alembic
├── run_flask_app.py


I'm happy to provide more detail and information if that helps.

I had db.init_app(app) twice...D'Uh.
